# How to apply answer key on students' responses

Tags: sql

I conducted a MCQs type test for students in Eng, math, and science
Students solved their test on a sheet readable by the OMR/OCR.
The machine produced responses of the students in follwoig way:-

```
Student ID     Subject   Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4 ......
201            English    3  1   4    1 ......
201            Math       3  2   1    1 ....
201            Science    2  1   2    3 ....
202            English    3  1   4    1 ......
202            Math       3  2   1    1 ....
202            Science    2  1   2    3 ....
-
-
-
```

How can i apply answer key on this data e.g for English my answer key is:

```
2   2   4   1 .....
```

would you pleas suggest a query for this situation

Comment: Do you have your key stored in a separate table?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide more detail about what approach you are using for this. What technology or platform are you using? Your question as it stands is too broad and is likely to be closed if left in it's current state.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
StudentId
,CASE WHEN Q2 = ?ANSWER? then 1 ELSE 0 END
,CASE WHEN Q3 = ?ANSWER? then 1 ELSE 0 END
,CASE WHEN Q4 = ?ANSWER? then 1 ELSE 0 END
,CASE WHEN Q5 = ?ANSWER? then 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM
Table
Where subject = 'English'
```

One of possible solutions replace ?ANSWER? with something from your answer key

Other would be to generate tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE EnglishKey(
QuestionId int,
Answer int)
```

Then insert your values in this way:

```
INSERT INTO EnglishKey VALUES (1,3),(2,4),(....)
```

Replacing 1 with question number and answer with proper answer.

And then creating a SELECT should be easy

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    a.StudentID
    CASE WHEN a.Q1 <> a.A1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end AS Result1,
    CASE WHEN a.Q2 <> a.A2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end AS Result2,
    CASE WHEN a.Q3 <> a.A3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end AS Result3,
    CASE WHEN a.Q4 <> a.A4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end AS Result4,
    CASE WHEN a.Q5 <> a.A5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end AS Result5,
    CASE WHEN a.Q6 <> a.A6 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end AS Result6,
    CASE WHEN a.Q7 <> a.A7 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end AS Result7,
    CASE WHEN a.Q8 <> a.A8 THEN 0 ELSE 1 end AS Result8
FROM 
    StudentTable a
    INNER JOIN AnswerTable b ON a.[SUBJECT] = b.[SUBJECT]
```

This answer presumes that you have the answers in a seperate table and can join on subject.

If you find it a pain to write out all the case statements (could have 100s of questions) you can quickly build these queries in Microsoft Excel or open office by breaking up the statement across multiple columns, have it fill in the 1,2,3,4s etc and then copy paste once happy.